# Convergence of the empirical distribution function

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Let $\alpha\in\mathbb R^d$, with $\alpha\neq 0$. Take a sequence of iid random variables $X^{1},\dots,X^{n}$ with values in $\mathbb R^d$ and denote $R$ the cdf of $\alpha X^1$ (where the product is a scalar product). Now consider $\alpha^n=g(X^{1},\dots,X^{n})$ for some function $g$, and suppose we know that $\alpha^n\to\alpha$ almost surely as $n\to\infty$. Define
$\hat R_n(t)=\frac{1}{n}\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf 1_{\left\{\alpha^nX^i\leq t\right\}},$
which is the empirical distribution of $\alpha^nX^{1},\dots, \alpha^nX^{n}$.
Can we say that $\hat R_n(t)\to R(t)$ as $n\to\infty$?

Comment: I think you need some additional assumption to ensure that
$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (1_{\{\alpha^n X^i \leq t\}} - 1_{\{\alpha X^i \leq t\}})
$ converges to $0$ almost surely.

Comment: maybe or maybe not, in one dimension it just works with no further assumptions...

Comment: Corresponding mathoverflow question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/153393/convergence-of-the-empirical-distribution-function

Answer (score 2):

You said that *"in one dimension it just works with no further assumptions..."*

Consider the following counterexample.

Let $X^1,X^2,\dots$ be i.i.d. random variables with distribution $P(X^i=1)=P(X^i=-1)=\frac{1}{2}$ and let $\alpha^n = \frac{1}{n} \longrightarrow \alpha = 0$. Then $R(0) = P(0 \leq 0) = 1$ but
$$
\hat{R}_n(0) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n 1_{\{X_i \leq 0\}} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{a.s.} \frac{1}{2}.
$$

Comment: yes I forgot to specify that $\alpha$ needs to be nonzero, I'll modify the question, thanks. You find a proof of that under the same question on mathoverflow.